# Are there any benefits to using bitmaps?

Tags: image, compact-framework

I'm porting some CF 2.0 VB.Net apps to a newer version of a handset that has twice the screen resolution. So I have to double the dimensions of everything otherwise it all gets squished up into the top LH corner of the screen.

One screen had a bitmap which was 250K in size, and after I doubled the dimensions naturally it blew out to one MB. This isn't real good on a handheld, so I fired up irfanview and converted it to a .GIF. The .GIF was only 60KB in size, with no discernible change in the quality of the image.

To me, it seems a no-brainer : Convert all Bitmaps to Gif (or JPG) and get the same results for a fraction of the disk space (and probably quicker form loading times).

But does anyone know of a situation where you would use a bitmap in preference to a GIF/JPEG? I cannot find any.

Comment: not answering your question, but .png usually provides slightly better compression that .gif

Comment: Keep in mind these compressed images have to be uncompressed before they can be used. If your device has 100K of free RAM, a 50K JPEG or PNG may cause your app to run out of memory during use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really can't think of any realistic example where you would prefer an bitmap to a GIF.  Since GIF is a lossless format you loose no information when storing images.  So after reading the file in your app you will have the same image data as if you have read a bitmap.  And like you said: The file will be smaller and thus will probably will be read faster from disk.

JPEG is different because it's a lossy format, meaning you will lose information when storing images in it.  You will need to decide if the loss of information is meaningful in your app.

Bitmaps would be preferable if and only if reading files from disk where faster than decompressing the file in memory.

And to be precise you would prefer bitmaps when storing images in main memory, so you can work easily on the data in your code.  Which is actually what you most likely already have when you have loaded a file using an image library.

Answer (score 1):

To cut a long story shorts, a BMP is stored as a series of pixels along with their colour. This is useful if you want to do such things as pattern recognition, movement detection and such like.

Bitmaps are typically used for their convenience - you can knock one up in paint without having specialist graphics software.